# Импорт сложной структуры каталогов по протоколу обмена 1с с сайтом

Tags: битрикс, 1с, commerceml

Доброго времени суток всем!

У меня вопрос к знатокам, работающим на Битрикс или на modx. Наверняка, решая сложные проекты, Вам приходилось сталкиваться с такой задачей, как интеграция с 1с интернет-магазина. Данная статья, что указана по этой [ссылке](http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/131/), гласит, что существует определенный протокол обмена данных между 1с и сайтом. Основной формат передачи заказов согласован по стандартам CommerceML.

Так вот в моем случае, используя этот протокол обмена данных, надо перебрать дерево каталогов с файлами:

```
Корневая папка/
     1/
          файл1.xml
          файл2.xml
          ...
          файлN.xml
     2/
          файл1.xml
          файл2.xml
          ...
          файлN.xml

          ...
     N/
          файл1.xml
          файл2.xml
          ...
          файлN.xml
     файл_xxxxxx.xml
     файл2_xxxxxx.xml
```

Так вот, согласно стандартам данного протокола обмена, там возможны следующие значения:

Для **type**:

1. **catalog**.
2. **sale**.

Для **mode**:

1. **checkauth**
2. **init**
3. **file**
4. **import**
5. **query**
6. **success**

Выгрузка осуществляться может так примерно:

> http://<сайт>/<путь> /1c_exchange.php?type=catalog&mode=import&filename=<имя файла>

Хотел спросить, как можно перебрать дерево каталогов с файлами правильно, используя протокол передачи данных 1с с сайтом. Он вообще на это способен? Кто этим занимался?

В моем случае получается, что он только читает файлы в корневой папке, то есть:

```
файл_xxxxxx.xml
файл2_xxxxxx.xml.
```